# Generating summary reports with Sitecore Webforms For Marketers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Sitecore with the Webforms For Marketers (WFFM) plugin. With WFFM I have created multiple forms. All the forms are working correctly, but by some forms an error occured by generating a Summary Report.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Stack trace:
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items]
   Sitecore.Form.UI.Converters.ListItemsAdapter.AdaptList(IList list) +330
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Utility.FieldReflectionUtil.ListAdapt(FieldItem field) +258
   Sitecore.Forms.Data.PoolManager.GetInitialApplicants(FieldItem fieldItem) +49
   Sitecore.Forms.Data.PoolManager.GetApplicants(FieldItem item, IEnumerable`1 polls, Boolean onlyDefined) +136
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDataViewerPage.LoadSummary() +476
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDataViewerPage.SummaryRender() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3554
```

You can generate a Summary Report by clicking on the Sitecore Start-button -> Web Forms for Marketers -> Form Reports. Select a form and click on the Summary tab.

I have looked at the working and not-working forms - and my conclusion is that I can found no difference in configuration. The strange thing is that every form stores the data correctly. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Comment: Are you using any custom form fields? Any fields that are more complex or stand out that are used in the broken reports?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm using custom form fields.

Comment: Can you find a pattern between these fields and the reports that don't want to load? (like there's always 1 custom control that only appears on the broken reports)

Comment: Great. The custom control is the cause of this error. Did you have any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: Can you add code and information regarding the custom control to your question? Perhaps we can pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't override the Result's class to output your custom field.

Here's an example of a custom RadioList with textbox. The output is whatever user select except if the user selected the last item in the radioList he/she must provide additional info.

```
   public override ControlResult Result
        {
            get
            {
                return new ControlResult(this.ControlName,
                                     (this.buttonList.SelectedItem != null 
                                        && this.buttonList.SelectedIndex == this.buttonList.Items.Count - 1
                                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.InputText.Text)) ?
                                     this.buttonList.SelectedItem.Text + ", " + this.InputText.Text :
                                     (this.buttonList.SelectedItem != null? this.buttonList.SelectedItem.Text  : string.Empty),
                                      this.buttonList.SelectedValue ?? string.Empty);

            }
        }
```

Hope this would help,
Dyni